# Is it possible to use Remote Desktop or a similar tool to manage iOS devices ?

Tags: macos, ios, remote-desktop, remote-control, apple-remote-desktop

I find it really useful to use Remote Desktop to manage OSX devices, Is it possible to use Remote Desktop or a similar tool to manage iOS devices ?

Comment: What specific features are you looking for? What do you mean by "manage"?

Comment: @ruddfawcett i manage the IT for a small company and as part of this i need to setup all our employees personal phones with the required email accounts, apps etc. Similarly i need to manage our company ipads.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator-2/id1037126344?mt=12).

Description from the Mac App Store:

> Apple Configurator 2 makes it easy to deploy iPad, iPhone, iPod touch, and Apple TV devices in your school or business.
>
> Use Apple Configurator 2 to quickly configure large numbers of devices connected to your Mac via USB with the settings, apps, and data you specify for your students, employees, or customers.